# Unable to install bleve, cannot find package "github.com/blevesearch/zap/v11" in any of

Tags: go, bleve

I cannot install bleve as it complains about zap:

go get github.com/blevesearch/bleve/...

```
package github.com/blevesearch/zap/v11: cannot find package "github.com/blevesearch/zap/v11" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v11 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/w/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v11 (from $GOPATH)
package github.com/blevesearch/zap/v12: cannot find package "github.com/blevesearch/zap/v12" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v12 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/w/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v12 (from $GOPATH)
package github.com/blevesearch/zap/v13: cannot find package "github.com/blevesearch/zap/v13" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v13 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/w/go/src/github.com/blevesearch/zap/v13 (from $GOPATH)
```

I can fetch it via gopkg.in/blevesearch/zap.v13, but bleve itself is referencing this.  My GOPATH is unset.

go env:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/w/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/w/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="freebsd"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="freebsd"
GOPATH="/home/w/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/freebsd_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build443146450=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: Without a [mre] we can only guess. Are you using a current version of Go? What is the output of `go env`?

Comment: What's your go version? Do you use go module and what does it look like if you use it?

Comment: I am using go 1.14.6 on FreeBSD.  I believe bleve uses go modules.  I would think my environment might not be right since this is a fairly popular project ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem and found that bleve now requires using of Go modules to be enabled. I see, in your env, that Go module (`GO111MODULE`) is not enabled. You need to enable Go module by adding this line in your `.bashrc` (or equivalent) file.

```
export GO111MODULE=on
```

Or you can use it directly in command when installing bleve.

```
GO111MODULE="on" go get -u github.com/blevesearch/bleve/...
```

But, if you use it in command line and do not put in your `.bashrc` file, you may need to use it when `go run` or `go build`. So it will be helpful to add it to `.bashrc`.

For more information, [check out this RFC](https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve/issues/1350).

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks, now to start using bleve :).